# AngularJS addclass: error addclass not a function

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS trying to `addclass` but getting error:

> addclass is not a function

```
$scope.viewReport = function(ev,element) 
{
        window.location="#tab7";
        $scope.tabact = document.getElementById('tab7');
        console.log($scope.tabact);
        $scope.tabact.addClass('active');
        $rootScope.callOrder = false
        $rootScope.step1=true
        $rootScope.step2=false
        $rootScope.step3=false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use addClass method if you can, but instead use a more angularish way: [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

So, in your html you can use something like this:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'active' : isActive }"> </div>
```

This way, you will have a cleaner code in your js:

```
$scope.viewReport = function(ev,element) {
    window.location="#tab7";
    $scope.isActive = true;
    //$scope.tabact = document.getElementById('tab7'); no longer needed
    //$scope.tabact.addClass('active'); no longer needed

            $rootScope.callOrder = false
    $rootScope.step1=true
            $rootScope.step2=false
            $rootScope.step3=false
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not correct way to add class in angular

In angular we have a directive `ng-class`, use that

Example :

HTML :

```
<span class="base-class" ng-class="myClass">Sample Text</span>
```

JS :

```
$scope.myClass = '';
$scope.viewReport = function() {
    // some conditions or code
    $scope.myClass = 'bigRedText';
}
```

CSS :

```
.bigRedText {
    color: red;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

Comment: Yes but I want to add it to uib-tabset  and tablet set already has ng-class

Comment: Check uib-tabs settings, https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs, you can give classes attibute there, if you want it dynamic try `classes="{{myClass}}"`